# What are the different approaches to versioning individual documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

If I add a property to a domain object, this will ripple down to the MongoDB document. For example, adding a new "facebookId" property to my users, will add a new facebookId field to my MongoDB documents.

What are the different approaches to keep track of documents versions ?

I was thinking about adding a "_version" field to all my documents. Are there any other solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the document schema version, there are few options:

1. You could add a `version` field to all documents or just those that are newer than the original schema (only add it when something changes from the original schema). Given that every byte counts in a BSON document, I'd keep it short and simple, like `_v : 1`. Depending on the consuming platform (like Node.JS, C#, Java, etc.), having a version may not make deserialization simple.
2. Use a system that detects version automatically by detecting certain data fields (like, only version `2` has `facebookId`). For simple cases, this could be easily handled in a model class by changing object behavior based on presence of the field. This is what I've done before and it works well in many scenarios.
3. Update all documents in a collection to reflect new schema. This could be done all in one pass in a brief system downtime (depending on the number of documents).
4. As needed, update a document (when a document is read, rewrite it if it doesn't match the current schema). I've used this in non-MongoDB systems ... and it can work well (but it should work well in MongoDB as well).

It makes things easier (especially #2 and #4) if the new field can be null/non-required.